# event tracking of post to facebook action

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-like

I'm trying to track event, when user completed post to facebook with help facebook like button. I found `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create')` and `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove')`, but they are not suitable for me, because it track "like" event. Have you any way to track post to facebook event?